# viewDidAppear is called before viewDidLayoutSubviews when using pushViewController

Tags: ios

Get a problem:
I am having view controller A setup in xib with auto layout and being pushed via `pushViewController` from home view controller. Home view controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

I tried to use `pushViewController`, push view controller B, another instance of the same class as A,

but I found that, the `viewDidAppear` is called in B even before the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

So when I tried to get a sub view's frame in `viewDidAppear`, it is not correct. What's wrong?

Some trace:

```
2015-10-23 15:02:25.277 Compass[8199:1698308] -[BarLineChartViewController viewWillAppear:] line 89 $ axis chart VC will appear
2015-10-23 15:02:25.286 Compass[8199:1698308] -[BarLineChartViewController viewDidAppear:] line 106 $ axis chart VC did appear
2015-10-23 15:02:25.293 Compass[8199:1698308] -[ChartViewController viewDidAppear:] line 126 $ chart vc viewDidAppear
2015-10-23 15:02:25.298 Compass[8199:1698308] -[BarLineChartViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews] line 95 $ axis chart VC will LayoutSubviews
2015-10-23 15:02:25.303 Compass[8199:1698308] -[BarLineChartViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews] line 95 $ axis chart VC will LayoutSubviews
2015-10-23 15:02:25.310 Compass[8199:1698308] -[BarLineChartViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews] line 100 $ axis chart VC did LayoutSubviews
```

Comment: I know this is a very old question. But want to know if it is resolved? Were you changing something in `viewDidAppear`? I'm currently trying to understand this flow and got to come here.

Comment: No. I didn't remember nor how do I workaround.

Comment: oh, no problem. Thanks!